# "Flattening" a pandas dataframe by doubling and concatenating?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `datframe` `df` in `pandas`:

```
na   nb   a    b
 1    2  12   a2
 1    5   1   c3
 2    5   5   a3
```

Now, I need to "flatten" the `df` to one column and add a "marker" `m` that tells me which part is coming from, so

```
 d   a   b   m
 1  12  a2   I
 2  12  a2   I
 1   1  c3   I
 5   1  c3   O
 2   5  a3   O
 5   5  a3   O
```

I've tried the following:

```
aa = df[["na","a","b"]]
ab = df[["nb","a","b"]]
aa["m"]="I" 
ab["m"]="O" 
aa.colums=["d","a","b"]
ab.colums=["d","a","b"]
```

and then,

```
a = pd.concat([aa, ab])
```

But I get a lot of warnings from "slice from a DataFrame" (the assignment), and "Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name" by naming the columns, though I thought I was renaming, not creating new ones.

Anyway, my question is: how do I "flatten" `df` in the most pythonic/pandasonic way?

Comment: `aa = df[..].copy()`, same for `ab`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it is just `melt`:

```
(df.melt(['a','b'], value_name='d')
   .assign(m=lambda x: np.where(x['variable'].eq('na'), 'I','O'))
   .drop('variable', axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
    a   b  d  m
0  12  a2  1  I
1   1  c3  1  I
2   5  a3  2  I
3  12  a2  2  O
4   1  c3  5  O
5   5  a3  5  O
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rename` columns names `na` and `nb` with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df1 = df.rename(columns={'na':'I', 'nb':'O'}).melt(['a','b'], value_name='d', var_name='m')

print (df1)
    a   b  m  d
0  12  a2  I  1
1   1  c3  I  1
2   5  a3  I  2
3  12  a2  O  2
4   1  c3  O  5
5   5  a3  O  5
```

Last if necessary change order of columns:

```
df1 = df1[['d','a','b','m']]
print (df1)
   d   a   b  m
0  1  12  a2  I
1  1   1  c3  I
2  2   5  a3  I
3  2  12  a2  O
4  5   1  c3  O
5  5   5  a3  O
```

Your solution should be changed, but I feel first is more pythonic:

```
aa = df[["na","a","b"]].rename(columns={'na':'d'}).assign(m='I')
ab = df[["nb","a","b"]].rename(columns={'nb':'d'}).assign(m='O')
a = pd.concat([aa, ab], ignore_index=True)

print (a)
   d   a   b  m
0  1  12  a2  I
1  1   1  c3  I
2  2   5  a3  I
3  2  12  a2  O
4  5   1  c3  O
5  5   5  a3  O
```